# jQuery .ajax() url parameter not taking concatenated string?

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of javascript that may be executed from a variety of pages with different URLs.  The code is working properly in this case (the key here is the url parameter, nothing else will be changing):

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "./ajax/getPageTitle",
           data: "pageID="+$("#pageToEdit").val(),
           success: function(pageName){
                $("#updatedPageName").val(pageName);  
           },
           error: function(req,error){
                if(error === 'error'){error = req.statusText;}
                alert("There was an error: " + error);
           }
        });
```

When I try to modify the url parameter to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: BASE_URL+"ajax/getPageTitle",
           data: "pageID="+$("#pageToEdit").val(),
           success: function(pageName){
                $("#updatedPageName").val(pageName);  
           },
           error: function(req,error){
                if(error === 'error'){error = req.statusText;}
                alert("There was an error: " + error);
           }
        });
```

where BASE_URL is a constant, it causes an error.  It seems the request isn't even being sent (no 404 errors in the console in firebug when I try) and the error message just says "error".

Works fine in the first one, when it happens to be on a page that the url parameter makes sense.  Any idea why this is happening and what a solution might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(BASE_URL+"ajax/getPageTitle")`

Comment: My bet is `BASE_URL` is missing a trailing slash

Comment: This is not a cross-domain request is it?

Comment: Unrelated, but while jQuery is ok with you building a string for the data property of your AJAX options, it is much more maintainable to use an object: `data: { pageID: $( '#pageToEdit' ).val() }`

Comment: @SLaks - I was checking that, but added your piece to be sure.  THe URL is correct.  Even if it wasn't, I would've been generating a 404 response on the Ajax call, which isn't happening here.

@Pekka Nope, it has the trailing slash

@no.good.at.coding Nope, same domain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. The problem is being caused by the inclusion of domain name in the BASE_URL. The value used to be "http://www.mydomain.com/base/url/" in the BASE_URL variable.  Once I dropped the "http://www.mydomain.com" it worked. So my BASE_URL became "/base/url/".